# program going into infinite loop after 15 seconds

Tags: c, loops

I am making a program to find prime factorials of a given number.
Although the program works fine, I have two problems.
1. when i enter an odd number, it prints 2 in the result although 2 should not be in it.
2. After 15 seconds , it turns into an infinite loop , Which is really creepy.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int num(int); // Making a function for finding prime factors
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter any number");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    num(i);

    getch();

    }

int num(int i)
{

    int a=2;
    while(a<=i)
    {

        if(i%a==0) //if the number is divisible then divide it
            i=i/a;

        printf(" %d",a);

        if(i%a!=0) 
       {
            i%a;
            while(i%a!=0)// If it is not divisible by 2 then increment it until it is
                 a++;
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: infinite occurs after the output

Comment: say i enter 56, then it will show me the factors , then after some time, it turns into an infinite loop

Comment: it just prints -1 repeatedly

Comment: This statement, `i%a;`  It does *nothing*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always prints 2 because the print statement is not part of the if which tests for mod 0. It goes into an infinite loop because once a passes i, the second while loop will never exit.

Comment: Thanks Sir !! My code is working properly now. And yes i will make the habit of using braces in "if" statements. :)

Answer (score 2):

The infinite loop is your second `while` loop, `while(i%a!=0)`.  For a prime number, this will continue endlessly.  There are smart ways to fix that, but at the very least, change it to

```
while(i%a!=0 && a<=i)
```

I'm not sure why 2 is coming up on odd numbers, still thinking that part through.

**EDIT** As Fred mentioned, the printout is not part of the if statement, causing 2 to always show up.  Personally, I recommend getting into the habit of always putting `{ }` after an `if` statement.  Even if you've been coding for decades, this will make sure you get the right statements in your condition.

Comment: but i have made the condition of a<=i in the first loop . do i need to do this in the second while loop too??

Comment: @KhalidAhmed Ask yourself this: what will make the second loop exit?